# 12.04 "Low Disk Space" message

Tags: partitioning

Upon boot I consistently receive a `Low Disk Space` warning informing me that "Filesystem root" has only XXXMB disk space remaining; XXX is diminishing with each boot and is getting dangerously low.

When I scan the filesystem with Disk Usage Analyzer it shows the Total filesystem capacity at 2.0TB (used: 154.0GB, available: 1.8TB).  This makes sense to me.

However, the ring chart (and table) shows the size of `/` at 153.5GB and warns that it's at 100% usage, with the largest files (those that are causing the so-called 100% usage) residing in `/home/looie/Documents`.

My partitions are setup with

- `/` sized at 14.30GB (`/dev/sda3`)
- `/home` (on `/dev/sda4`) at 1.8TB.

I want my documents to be stored on `/home/looie/Documents` on `/dev/sda4` but they appear to ALSO be stored on `/home/looie/Documents` on `/dev/sda3` causing the partition to approach it maximum capacity and generate the `Low Disk Space` warning.

What am I doing wrong?  How can I set things up so that my data "Documents" is stored on the partition with the greatest capacity (`/dev/sda4`) and NOT on the smaller partition (`/dev/sda3`)?

Thanks

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you see what the fstab file sais about `/home`? (gksu gedit /etc/fstab)

Comment: Just to make sure Disk analyzer is not getting confused: go to `Edit -> Preferences` and check that only your root device is selected. Then scan (only) the root filesystem again.

Comment: Here is the output of gksu gedit /etc/fstab: !http://imgur.com/EPjaWFM

Answer (score 0):

Unmount your `/home` partition (with Gparted or command line) and then look to make sure /home is empty (as it should be). Delete or move anything that doesn't belong. Then either mount your `/home` partition again or just reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm still confused.  Why would I want "/home", which I've set up with 1.8TB of space to contain all my data in "/home/looie/Documents" to be empty?

Comment: Because `/home` will only have `looie` or anything else if your 1.8TB of space is mounted. If that space is not mounted to `/home`, then it everything there will be stored wherever `/` is mounted. Basically, you want to make sure that if your 1.8TB partition isn't mounted to `/home`, then there shouldn't be any data there.